# Provide internet access on the GCP side to an advertised bgp route

Tags: vpn, routing, google-cloud-platform, bgp

I have been looking for a solution for the above for a few days now and I've not come across a config that works.

**Current setup:**

I have a GCP CloudVPN with dynamic routing setup with an external provider. The advertised routes are received properly. The vpn tunnels and bgp sessions are established. It's all green in the GCP console.

PINGs across both sides also are successful. In addition I've setup an instance as a NAT gateway (external ip) and created a new default route that points to the NAT instance gateway. A vm in the vac network has the correct NAT ip when outbound queries are made - e.g curl ifconfig.co - returns the public ip as configured.

**We would like to have the advertised routes (from the provider) use our GCP default 0.0.0.0/0 route for internet access.**

Can anyone suggest how to make this work?

Comment: Do you want to route the traffic from GCP instances to the Internet via the VPN or the opposite ?